# Trying to make contents in a DIV scroll horizontally once their combined width is over the DIV max-width, however they only scroll vertically

Tags: html, css

Want to make the `<li><div class="ImgAndDel"></div></li>` scroll horzontally inside `.ProductImageGallery`
but they only clear at the end of the div and I get a vertical scroll only.

Here's the JSFIDDLE

[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/zDmeA/5/)

Comment: give the fiddle of only the component where the problem exists.. not the entaire code!!.. some of us are not that patient enf to read the whole code!!

Comment: Hmm I would think with CSS the context and layout within which any one style is applied is vital.

Comment: yeah,but you can break down the problem into its unitary state and post it instead of givin such huge content to work with.. as a result -- no hits!!.. no one bothers to read and go through your entaire code to help you out.. my point is,the smaller -- quicker help you'll get..

Comment: I can see what you are saying, but honestly in my case there's nothing there bar the form tags and some hidden inputs that I could really remove without compromising the layout, since it's one structure with DIV's floated left or right in respect to one another.

Answer (score 0):

from what i can think of , your problem was that it was not in a single line.. i.e,all those blocks.. hence,there was no horizontal scroll ..

You were'nt giving it enough width for the blocks with `float:left` to fill in one line.. without enough width it cannot fit it one line.. hence,it was going to the next line inturn giving you a vertical scroll..

by line i mean in one block of horizontal space..

corrected to my best efforts..

hope this is what you were looking for -- http://jsfiddle.net/mvivekc/zDmeA/10/